# Time Complexity of Subset Problem

Tags: complexity-theory, java

The Subset Exercise taken from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/):

```
Example: For Input nums = [1,2,3] Return Output:
    [
      [3],
      [1],
      [2],
      [1,2,3],
      [1,3],
      [2,3],
      [1,2],
      []
    ]
```

has as backtrack solution:

```
public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    backtrack(list, new ArrayList<>(), nums, 0);
    return list;
}

private void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list , List<Integer> tempList, int [] nums, int start){
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
    for(int i = start; i < nums.length; i++){
        tempList.add(nums[i]);
        backtrack(list, tempList, nums, i + 1);
        tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

The solution has been taken [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/discuss/27281/A-general-approach-to-backtracking-questions-in-Java-(Subsets-Permutations-Combination-Sum-Palindrome-Partitioning)).
I would like to know what the time and space complexities of this solution are. Apparently, the time complexity is `O(N * 2^n)`. The `N` come from the `tempList.add()` operation, I have a problem understanding where the `2^N` come from.

Comment: Because given a set `M`, its [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) `P(M)` has a cardinality of `2^|M|`, meaning there are `2^|M|` subsets to generate. Also note that `ArrayList::add` is only O(n) in the worst case, it is O(1) amortised.

Comment: I think a factor O(n) will come from the fact that you are constructing sets which have n/2 elements on average, and constructing sets might not work in constant time.

Comment: @Emily if you write a proper answer I will mark it as the right one